# Debugging help "Attempt to invoke method on null object reference"

Tags: android, debugging, object, methods, reference

Hello I am needing some help on a very simple issue. My app crashes when I click on a second button I've created.

I understand that the app thinks there is no object when I click the button but it is all labeled correctly I believe. Take a look.

these are all the components for the one that crashes the app:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification_shot;

public void clk_shot(View v) {
    //Shot Build

    **notification_shot.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_shot);
    notification_shot.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification_shot.setContentTitle("drink up");
    notification_shot.setContentText("cheers");
    notification_shot.setLights(0xffffff00, 1000, 3000);
    notification_shot.setAutoCancel(false);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification_shot.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

**from the debug report I get this line**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.setSmallIcon(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.weibapps.test.icons.MainActivity.clk_shot(MainActivity.java:58)
```

**Line 58 is marked with ** in my above code**

it has the small icon next to the line which I believe means the app knows what icon to pull. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a second button I have that works perfectly fine.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notification_mari = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification_mari.setAutoCancel(false);
}

public void clk_mari(View view) {
    //Mari Build

    notification_mari.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mari);
    notification_mari.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification_mari.setContentTitle("light");
    notification_mari.setContentText("up");
    notification_mari.setLights(0xff00ff00, 500, 500);
    //End Build Components
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification_mari.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    //has intent

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueID, notification_mari.build());
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have searched but really have not found an answer to this specific issue.

Comment: Apparently `notification_shot` is null. Have you debugged it?

Comment: You never initialize `notification_shot`. Look at the very top of the first bit of code you posted.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you. What can I add to insure it is initialized?

Comment: Look at how `notification_mari` was initialized for the other button. Did you write that code?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I believe it is fixed, the app doesn't crash anymore. My button won't display what I need it to yet but I can fix it most likely. I wrote just about all of it myself, but I did take some pointers online mostly for formatting. I am quite new to this, your help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: Add this line Top of the code. notification notification_shot = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this); it should work.

Comment: @FajarKhan yes I was able to get it to stop crashing, thank you.

Comment: @FajarKhan that line is what I added too!

Comment: Your welcome! Glad it's resolved!